# How can I avoid duplicate code when I create a query builder?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Good morning, I have an order's service. Here I have two methods find( findAll ) and findByKey( find all by keys ) because it is a query builder I need to join in other tables.

Method find:

```
find(): Promise<Order[]> {
    return this.orderRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.restaurant', 'restaurant')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'media')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderCustomer', 'orderCustomer')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('order.orderCart', 'orderCart')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('orderCart.product', 'product')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('product.media', 'product_media')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderPayment', 'orderPayment')
      .getMany();
  }
```

Method findByKey:

```
findByKey(data: FindByKeyInput): Promise<Order[]> {
    const { field, value } = data;
    return this.orderRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .where(`order.${field} = :${field}`, { [field]: value })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.restaurant', 'restaurant')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'media')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderCustomer', 'orderCustomer')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('order.orderCart', 'orderCart')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('orderCart.product', 'product')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('product.media', 'product_media')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderPayment', 'orderPayment')
      .getMany();
  }
```

How Can I avoid this duplication, Can I put this part of the code into a variable and reuse it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one function with optional params, something like:

```
find(data: FindByKeyInput = { field=null, value=null }): Promise<Order[]> {
const { field, value } = data;
let query = this.orderRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('order') ;

 if(field != null && value != null)
 query.where(`order.${field} = :${field}`, { [field]: value });

 query.leftJoinAndSelect('order.restaurant', 'restaurant')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderCustomer', 'orderCustomer')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('order.orderCart', 'orderCart')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('orderCart.product', 'product')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('product.media', 'product_media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderPayment', 'orderPayment')
  .getMany();
 return query
   }
```

**UPDATE** 
to do what you desire, you can create a function that return the querybuilder:

```
getOrderRepoWithRelations(){
 return  this.orderRepository
   .createQueryBuilder('order')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.restaurant', 'restaurant')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderCustomer', 'orderCustomer')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('order.orderCart', 'orderCart')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('orderCart.product', 'product')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('product.media', 'product_media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderPayment', 'orderPayment')
}
```

then you can use it in your functions like:

```
find(): Promise<Order[]> {
return this.getOrderRepoWithRelations()
  .getMany();
 }


 findByKey(data: FindByKeyInput): Promise<Order[]> {
    const { field, value } = data;
    let query = this.getOrderRepoWithRelations();
    return query
      .where(`order.${field} = :${field}`, { [field]: value })
      .getMany();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it can be one solution, but the problem is that I encounter duplicate code and also in the others functions, where I can not combine them into one service's function.

Comment: check the update

Answer (score 0):

You also can use *.clone()* method.

```
//1. create a common query builder
const queryBuilder = this.orderRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('order')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.restaurant', 'restaurant')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderCustomer', 'orderCustomer')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('order.orderCart', 'orderCart')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('orderCart.product', 'product')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('product.media', 'product_media')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.orderPayment', 'orderPayment');

// 2. clone and add more queries to it
const firstQueryResult = await queryBuilder.clone().getMany()

const secondQueryResult = await queryBuilder.clone()
  .where(`order.${field} = :${field}`, { [field]: value })
  .getMany()
```

But, I mostly use *clone()* method to reuse the same queryBuilder multiple times, such as when I want to fetch the list of items based on some filter and get the count as well.
For example

```
const queryPrice = 10
const page= 1
const limit = 20
const queryBuilder = productRepo.createQueryBuilder('prod')
  .select('prod.id', 'id')
  .addSelect('prod.name', 'productName')
  .addSelect('prod.price', 'productPrice')
  .where('prod.price > :queryPrice', {queryPrice})
const count = await queryBuilder.clone().getCount()
const products = await queryBuilder.clone()
  .orderBy('prod.price', 'DESC')
  .skip((page - 1) * size)
  .take(limit)
  .getMany();
```